# I want to create a tool which will convert sas code into equivalent python code automatically how to do this....?

Tags: python, sql, database, nlp, sas

I have a database where number of converted sas code and python code is stored. the conversion should work dynamically and if the sequence of the input code changes this are the requirements.

Im facing issue in dynamic code conversion and if the sequence of the input code changes.

Comment: That is called a transpiler or source-to-source compiler. make will keep track of whether an input file changed, so you could make a script that calls make every x seconds.

Comment: You can spend a lifetime trying to accomplish this: it isn't a simple task. This is a Holy Grail of SAS conversions. If your SAS code is very, very simple (think SQL), you might be able to pull off a part of it. Many people have worked on this problem, many PhDs in CompSci. You need to narrow the scope A LOT to be able to do any part of it.

Comment: Let me get a clarification (after reading this multiple times). Do you have the SAS code and the Python code already stored together? Is the SAS code already converted and you are just checking to see if the SAS code changed?

Comment: If you're talking about building unit/regression tests (per AlanC) that is doable. If you're looking to build a code translator for any SAS code to python, that will be a very cumbersome task. SAS has been around for 50+ years and has a lot of nuances to it, including the macro language that will make conversion difficult. You'll also need to convert SQL. Interactions with the OS/other languages are also supported so you've got a lot there to work through if you want a general solution. You could limit it to a few basic concepts maybe.

Comment: We're doing a conversion from Oracle to MS SQL - there are conversion tools right now, and they all get us 70% of the way there but then we have to review everything manually anyways and check it. The time savings is there but not great.